# Proof that if $a \gt 1$ and $r \gt s$, then $a^{r} \gt a^{s}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to prove the sentence above but I'm not getting results, I'm learning precalculus yet. Could someone help me find the starting point to prove the sentence above?

Comment: I don't see how your question had changed. For less than, just rename the variables. Instead of r-s, consider s-r, and so on. The logic is symmetrical

Comment: I decided to keep the question originally as it was, because it still maintains logic. Regardless of everything, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be difficult, since exponentials for non-integer exponents are defined in a rather complicated way. But, you could argue that if we let $t=r-s$, we get:

\begin{align*}
a^r = a^{s+t} = a^{s} \cdot a^t
\end{align*}

Since $a>1$ and $t>0$, we have that $a^t > 1$ (can you convince yourself of this?). Therefore $a^r > a^s$ (in particular since $a^r > 0$).

Comment: It took me long enough to understand, but now I understood. Thank you for resolving my doubt.

Answer (score 1):

You can write $$a^r = a^s a^{r-s}$$
Because $a>1$, $a^{r-s}$ is greater than 1 when the exponent is greater than 0, and given to us is that $r>s$ so $r-s>0$. This gives that $a^r$ is $a^s$ times some number greater than one. Therefore, $a^r > a^s$

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: If $a > 0$ then $a^s > 0$ for all $s$.

Step 2:  If $a > 1$ then if $s > 0$ then $a^s> 1$ and if $s = 0$ then $a^s = 1$ and if $s < 0$ then $0 < a^s < 1$.

Step 3:  If $r > s$

The $r - s > 0$ so $a^{r-s} > 1$

But $a^{r-s} = \frac {a^s}{a^r}$ so $\frac {a^s}{a^r} > 1$.

And as $a^s > 0$ we get $a^r > a^s$.

....

Proving 1) and 2) for integers is easy.  Proving 1) and 2) for rationals is clear if you raise everything to a common multiple of the denominators of $r$ and $s$.  Prove 1) and 2) for reals depends on how real exponents were defined.  But if they were defined as limits then the result follows by taking limits.

Answer (score 0):

There exist rational numbers satisfying

$$\frac{q_{1}}{p_{1}}> r> \frac{q_2}{p_2} > s > \frac{q_3}{p_3}.$$

(Assume $p_1, p_2, p_3$ are positive integers.)

Because

$$\frac{q_1 p_2}{p_1 p_2} =\frac{q_{1}}{p_{1}}> \frac{q_2}{p_2} = \frac{p_1 q_2}{p_1 p_2},$$

and because $p_1 p_2$ is positive integer, we know that $q_1 p_2 > p_1 q_2$.

$a>1$. Hence,

$$\cdots>a^2>a^1 = a > a^0=1 > a^{-1} = \frac{1}{a} > a^{-2} = \frac{1}{a^2} > \cdots.$$

It means that if $m>n$ are integers, then $a^m > a^n$. Thus,

$$a^{q_1 p_2} > a^{p_1 q_2} > 0.$$

If $x>y>0$ and $t$ is a positive integer, then $x^{\frac{1}{t}} > y^{\frac{1}{t}}>0$. Thus,

$$a^{\frac{q_{1}}{p_{1}}} = a^{\frac{q_1 p_2}{p_1 p_2}} > a^{\frac{p_1 q_2}{p_1 p_2}}
= a^{\frac{q_2}{p_2}}. $$

And (by omitting rigorous explanation,)

$$ a^{\frac{q_{1}}{p_{1}}} > a^r > a^{\frac{q_2}{p_2}}. $$

Similarly, we can show that

$$a^{\frac{q_2}{p_2}} > a^s > a^{\frac{q_3}{p_3}}. $$

Thus, $a^r > a^s$.